# C program does not have output

Tags: c

[C I am a beginner ][1]

I dont know what the problem with my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int fahr;
  for (fahr = 320; fahr = 0; fahr = fahr - 20)
    printf("%d %f \n", fahr, (5.0 / 9.0) *.(fahr - 32));
}
```

Comment: `for (fahr = 320; fahr = 0; fahr =  fahr - 20)`?? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: `fahr = 0` is not a comparison, it's setting the value.  use `==` (but ... is this the comparison you really want?)

Comment: One of the problems with the code is that it's producing warnings. Always enable compiler warnings and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: You might also consider using the more succinct `(fahr - 32.0) * 5 / 9`, which will give you the same result. Only *one* of the items in an two-term expression has to be the type with higher rank to get the other one automatically upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fahr = 0` is the killer. It assigns 0 to fahr, sees it's false, and stops without iterating.

`fahr == 0` would stop as desired but it would allow underruns if 0 is somehow skipped. Not a problem in this tiny fragment but it can be a life saver in larger and more complex loops where an extra decrement causes the value to skip 0 and happily march to negative infinity, which wraps back to positive and starts again. `fahr >=0` is what I would code.

(edit: fixed stupid bug)

Comment: it should be `fahr >= 0`

Comment: Bill is correct (as he often is). The second stanza in the `for` statement is the *continuation* condition, not the termination condition. What you have will also print nothing, because the continuation condition is immediately false.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
int main()
{
  int fahr;
  for (fahr = 320; fahr > 0; fahr = fahr - 20)
  {
    printf("%d %f \n", fahr,(5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
  }
    
  return 0;
}
```

I see two points: the condition to stop the for and the point after the *.

Answer (score 1):

1. `main` has return type `int`. Use it correctly
2. in the `for` loop `fahr = 0` assigns zero to `fahr`. You want logical operator there - probably `fahr != 0`
3. `*.(fahr - 32))` - it is invalid syntax in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int fahr;
  for (fahr = 320; fahr != 0; fahr = fahr - 20)
    printf("%d %f \n", fahr, (5.0 / 9.0) *(fahr - 32));
}
```

Comment: I had change the code and still not working

main()
{
  int fahr;
  for (fahr = 320; fahr == 0; fahr = fahr - 20)
  printf("%d %f \n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
  return 0;
}

Comment: @Winson: so you changed the code to something *other* than this answer suggested and you're having issues? Do you see the problem there? :-) Use `!=` rather than `==`.